# How to get values resolved in template without double curly brackets

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template

I am using directive and template. My template is as follows

```
<div>
    <a data-my-dir="item" data-attr1="true"
        data-attr2="{{itemParentId}}"
        data-attr3="{{item.id}}">
    </a>
</div>
```

Here due to curly braces watches are added and it is affecting my performance. I don't want watches as I am not going to modify attr2 or attr3.
I want to directly resolved value here only.

We can use bindonce directive where we don't want watches where we can use bo-text="xyz" instead, but here I want to pass values as attr to my custom directive.

Inside my directive's link function I am binding click event with element as follows

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('click', function (event) {
        var myAttr1 = attrs.attr1;
        var myAttr2 = attrs.attr2;
    }
}
```

So due to those watches in template on attr1 and attr2 I am getting these values resolved in click event.

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One time Binding

Seems like a good use case for [one time binding](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html) (*if you are using angular 1.3+*)

```
<div>
    <a data-my-dir="item" 
        data-attr1="true"
        data-attr2="{{::itemParentId}}"
        data-attr3="{{::item.id}}">
    </a>
</div>
```

the directive would look like

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive("myDir", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
         "attr1": "@",
         "attr2": "@",
         "attr3": "@",
      },
      template: '<span> {{attr1}} {{attr2}} {{attr3}}</span>'
    };
  })
```

### Demo

## http://plnkr.co/edit/GJCZmb9CTknZZbcRHN7s?p=preview

Comment: I am on angular 1.2. So its not working. Is there any other option to achieve this.

Comment: @IfOnly, sorry it's not suitable for 1.2... you can also inherit the relevant scope variables (e.g. no scope isolation) and this will give you direct access to these variables (no additional binding watches). should i make an example?

Comment: I edited my question to explain how I use attr in directive

Answer (score 0):

You could use `data-attr2="itemParentId"` directly but for that you need to use `=` as currently you are using `@` option of directive.

```
app.directive('myDir', function(){
    return {
       scope: {
           dataAttr1: '=', //or '=dataAttr1'
           dataAttr2: '=' //or '=dataAttr2'
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs){
           console.log(scope.dataAttr1);
           console.log(scope.dataAttr2);
       }
    }
})
```

Comment: I edited my question to explain how I use attr in directive